# Will meat taste okay if I cook it in a pan where the leftover fond seems burned?

Tags: chicken, meat, sauce, frying, food-science

I have found that after 2 batches of chicken breasts, the [fond](http://food52.com/blog/12331-how-to-make-sauce-out-of-your-pan-s-brown-bits-a-k-a-fond) is in the pan for enough time to start burning, so the third batch gets a little black and starts to taste burned.

Does it mean that I should deglaze or wash my pan every 2 batches to make sure I won't get a burned taste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd deglaze the pan after each pan and transfer the juices to a small bowl to make a sauce

I would wipe/clean (no soap) the pan after each batch.

After the last batch, transfer the bowl content and make a sauce with the last pan drippings and what you already have.

Comment: If you have a wooden spatula, and you have the water nearby, deglazing typically only takes 20-30 sec, even for larger pans.  (as it has a wide contact area, so you can scrape the fond very quickly). It might take a minute or two for the temperature to recover, though, depending on your burner.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use two or more pans, that way the fond would be nicely browned and usable for your sauce.